# How can I replace user permission with icacls in CMD?

Tags: cmd

First I used the command `icacls C:\Test /grant User:(OI)(CI)(RX)`.

Then I tried using the command `icacls C:\Test\Folder /grant:r User:(OI)(CI)M` for replacing user permissions but unsuccessfully.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly (what kind of permissions) ?

Comment: I'm trying replace the inherited permission but the permission for user has been duplicated.